# JMS: How do I connect my localhost glassfish server to the project I am working on?

Tags: java, jms, messaging, spring-messaging

I am new to JMS and APIs. I started working on a messaging platform to try and connect the Glassfish local server to start sending and receiving messages through the server.
However, I don't understand how to set up the Initial Context to recognize where the server is, and what to connect to.
When I run this, I get a NoInitialContextException.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.jms.*;

public class Sender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            QueueConnectionFactory f = (QueueConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory");
            QueueConnection con = f.createQueueConnection();
            con.start();
            QueueSession ses=con.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            //3) get the Queue object
            Queue t=(Queue)ctx.lookup("PTPQueue");
            //4)create QueueSender object
            QueueSender sender=ses.createSender(t);
            //5) create TextMessage object
            TextMessage msg=ses.createTextMessage();

            //6) write message
            BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Enter Msg, end to terminate:");
                String s=b.readLine();
                if (s.equals("end")) {
                    break;
                }
                msg.setText(s);
                //7) send message
                sender.send(msg);
                System.out.println("Message successfully sent.");
            }
            //8) connection close
            con.close();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected it to try to connect with the server, but nothing happened. How do I change this so that I can access the server? I have heard of a jndi.properties file but I am not sure how to use that here.
I am using Intellij, so is there an easy fix to connect the server there and work from there?